# Adjusting plotrange in Matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm looking for the equivalent of Mathematica's PlotRange -> {0,Pi} in a Matlab plot.  If I plot a function, for example:

```
t = linspace(0, pi, 100) ;
plot( t, cos(t) )
```

I get a plot that over the [0,3.5] interval, instead of [0,pi], as the following figure shows:

[image: cos plot sample]

Comment: Matlab will use regularly spaced ticks, so if the plot limits are not defined it will end in one of the regularly spaced tick. Use `xlim([0 pi])` to limit the x axis to end in pi.

Comment: Interesting: fplot(@cos,[0,pi]) sets the XLim property correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t = linspace(0, pi, 100) ;
plot( t, cos(t) )
%% Change Xaxis Limits
xlim([0 pi])
%% Set current plot axis (gca) Xtick and XtickLabel to manually input data
set(gca, 'XTick',[0,0.25*pi,.5*pi,0.75*pi,pi]);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'0','\pi/4','\pi/2','3 \pi/4','\pi'});

%% See matlab 2015 version help
```

[MATLAB 2015 Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html)